# Code to check if HTML input is valid

Tags: java

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class HTMLChecker {
    
    private String text;
    private String[] tags;
    private int tagNum;
    private ArrayStack<String> stack;
    
    public HTMLChecker (String input) {
        tags = new String[5];
        text = input;
        stack = new ArrayStack<String>();
        
        parseText();
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Check if the given tag is already contained in the array of tags. If not, it adds it to
     * the array, otherwise nothing is done. This is so we can avoid duplicate tags.
     * @param tag the tag that has just been encountered in HTML to be added to the array, unless
     * it has been added previously
     */
    public void addTagToArray (String tag) {
        boolean found = false;
        
        // Loop through array and check if the input tag is already there.
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            if (tags[i] != null && tags[i].equals(tag)) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        
        // If the tag was found in the array, then do nothing. Otherwise, add it to the array.
        if (!found) {
            
            // Expand capacity if needed.
            if (tagNum == tags.length) {
                expandCapacity();
            }
            
            // Add tag to array and increment counter;
            tags[tagNum] = tag;
            tagNum++;
            
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Expand the array's capacity by adding 5 additional slots.
     */
    private void expandCapacity () {
        String[] larger = new String[tags.length + 5];
        
        // Transfer existing items to the new, larger array.
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            larger[i] = tags[i];
        }
        
        tags = larger;
    }
    
    /**
     * Print out the array of tags that were found in the HTML input.
     */
    public void printTagList () {
        String str = "";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            
            if (tags[i] != null) {
                str += tags[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    
    public void parseText(){
        String tag = "";
        int flag = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) {
            if(text.charAt(i) == '<') {
                for(int j = i + 1; text.charAt(j) != '>'; j++) {
                    tag += text.charAt(j);
                    i = j;
                }
            } if(!tag.equals("")) {
                if(tag.charAt(0) != '/') {
                    stack.push(tag);
                } else if(tag.charAt(0) == '/') {
                    if(!stack.isEmpty() && tag.equals("/" + stack.pop())) {
                        addTagToArray(tag.substring(1));
                    } else  {
                        flag=1;
                        break;
                    }
               }
               tag = "";
            }
        }
          
      if(flag == 0 && stack.isEmpty()) {
          System.out.print("The HTML is  formatted correctly: ");
          printTagList();
      } else {
          System.out.println("The HTML is NOT formatted correctly.");
      }
  }
    
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        String s1 = "Stacks are helpful in many computer applications</h2>";
        new HTMLChecker(s1);

        String s2 = "<p>Java is my favourite language!</p><p>Programming is fun";
        new HTMLChecker(s2);

        String s3 = "<h1><i>I am learning a lot in CS 1027!</h1></i>";
        new HTMLChecker(s3);

        String s4 = "<table><tr><td>Python</td><td>Java</td></tr><tr><td>1026</td><td>1027</td></tr></table>";
        new HTMLChecker(s4);
        
        String s5 = "<html><head><title>My Website</title></head><body><h1>Welcome to my website!</h1><p>This is my website about Java programming.</p><p>Thanks for stopping by.</p></body></html>";
        new HTMLChecker(s5);

        
    }

}
```

I need help reviewing parseText(), everything else is correct.
Everything prints to HTML is not formatted correctly. However, the last two should be the other.

Comment: What you are doing is checking if the input is valid `XML`. `HTML` is different: consiter the tag `<br>` : it is perfectly valid in HTML to have this tag without a closing pair, and the string  `Foo <br> Bar <br> Baz` is a valid HTML and it will fail your test.

Comment: Are you assuming XHTML? You should check the doctype to know which version you're validating.

Comment: Is your code working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here is your input correctly formatted:

```html
Stacks are helpful in many computer applications</h2>
```

```html
<p>Java is my favourite language!</p>
<p>Programming is fun
```

```html
<h1><i>I am learning a lot in CS 1027!</h1></i>
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Python</td>
        <td>Java</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1026</td>
        <td>1027</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
        <p>This is my website about Java programming.</p>
        <p>Thanks for stopping by.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the last two *are* valid HTML.

Let me continue with saying that what is "valid" HTML is a...complicated matter. For over 20 years the browsers have tried to make the most sense of the HTML they get thrown at, and what constitutes "valid" HTML is in the eye of the beholder at this point. However, ideally, everyone would stick to these rules.

---

```java
private String text;
```

`text` is not the correct name in this case, it should be either `input` or `html`/`htmlContent`.

---

`tags` is needlessly an array, using a `Set` would remove much of the code for handling it. A `LinkedHashSet` would preserve the order of the encountered if that is required, otherwise a "normal" `HashSet` will do.

That will remove `tagNum`, `addTagToArray` and `expandCapacity` completely.

---

```java
private ArrayStack<String> stack;
```

You omitted the information what this class. I mean, we can deduce that it implements `java.util.Stack`, but it would still be nice to know.

Also, it should be declared with its base interface.

```
private Stack<String> stack = new ArrayStack<>();
```

Also also, `stack` is not a great name. `encounteredTags` or `foundTags` would be better.

---

```java
public HTMLChecker (String input) {
```

Validators accepting the to-be-checked-input in the constructor is unusual, it should have a `check` method which accepts the input.

---

```java
    public void printTagList () {
        String str = "";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            
            if (tags[i] != null) {
                str += tags[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

You want to use `StringBuilder` whenever concatening from an undefined-length list. As concatening `String`s like this will result in constant copying of the content. What happens is this:

1. Allocate memory in the size of `a`+`b`, call it `c`
2. Copy `a` into `c`
3. Copy `b` into `c`

And repeat for every iteration. If you have 25 characters, it doesn't matter. If you have 25 *million* characters, it starts to get a problem.

---

```java
public void parseText(){
```

Again, this is not a great name, neither is `flag`.

---

```java
tag += text.charAt(j);
```

You want to iterate until you find the end of the tag, and the copy the whole substring instead of single characters.

---

```java
!tag.equals("")
```

`!tag.isEmpty()` is easier to read.

---

A better structure for the class would be (a little pseudo-code):

```java
public class HtmlChecker {
    protected Set<String> tags;
    
    public HtmlChecker() {
        super();
    }
    
    public boolean parse(String html) { ... }
    public Set<String> getTags() { ... }
}

// Usage follows

HtmlChecker htmlChecker = new HtmlChecker();

if (htmlChecker.parse(input)) {
    System.out.println("input is valid HTML, encountered tags:");
    
    for (String tag : htmlChecker.getTags()) {
        System.out.println(" * " + tag);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("input is not valid HTML.");
}
```

---